# PHP ob_ functions usage

Tags: php

Just for curiosity: Is there any advantage by using this?

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html>
 <!--Page contents-->
</html>
<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none.

However, `ob_start` can take a callback parameter which is extremely useful. I use it to append `/t=FILEMTIME` to all static files, ensuring that all files are updated immediately when I upload them.

Also, you can use `header`, `session_start`, `setcookie` and other functions that operate on headers at any time, instead of having to worry whether you've started sending output yet or not.

Finally, those last lines are a very expensive no-op. The output buffer is processed at the end of the script anyway.